# Calculating the expected value without knowing the probabilities

Tags: expected-value, descriptive-statistics

I might be just missing something obvious, but I am asked the following:

> Consider the variables  and . The realization of a sample size of
> 20 is given below (where  is the first variable and  is the
> second):
>
> (−1.202, 563.024), (2.112, 291.072), (2.827, −893.619), (−0.314,
> 1321.814), (−1.477, −91.573), (−6.516, 446.336), (−0.920, −111.487), (3.477, −153.165), (−7.273, 1076.221), (2.251, 477.931), (−0.713,
> 909.696), (−0.853, 226.865), (−3.176, 389.413), (1.913, −47.169), (−1.070, −178.695), (−3.385, 744.486), (−9.506, 362.670), (−7.004,
> 364.578), (0.504, 324.975), (2.861, −360.571)
>
> Sketch an appropriate plot that displays the values of these points.
> Calculate the sample covariance as well as the sample’s expectations
> and the variances of  and .

How would I calculate the expected value? It's value times probability, but that's all the info I have to solve it. What do I need to do?

Thanks in advance for some pointers.

Comment: You are asking a good question. I believe the question is asking you to calculate the sample average of $X$ and $Y$ which for $X$ is given by $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and likewise for $Y$. One way to think about this is if we have $n$ independent samples from a common distribution $X$, then the sample average will be a good approximation for the true expectation.

Comment: Yep, your teacher probably meant to write "mean", rather than "expectation". Teachers are people too, they mess up sometimes!

Comment: OK, thanks guys, this helps me out a lot :) I'll clarify this with the teacher.

Comment: Indeed, based on the information provided, the expectation of X and Y correspond to the mean as described in Wikipedia (Definition - Finite Case) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value. Since your question does no longer require an answer, you might want to delete it to avoid that it queues for ever in the unanswered question list.